# Click on React-pdf Outline Results in Error: Invalid pageIndex request

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-typescript, react-pdf

I have a nextjs 14 app and am using react-pdf to view a pdf.  I have the outline pane which lists the items in the outline.  However, when i click on one, i get the error:

Error: Invalid pageIndex request.

I have validated the PDF by using other tools and they successfully navigate to the respective pages in the outline.

I have also tried to get the outline object onLoadSuccess of the outline, but dont seem to get the object.

The Next and Previous buttons work as expected ...

Here is the code:

```
  function onDocumentLoadSuccess({ numPages }: { numPages: number }): void {
    setNumPages(numPages);
  }

  function onItemClick({ pageNumber: itemPageNumber }: { pageNumber: number }) {
    console.log("** onItemClick: " + itemPageNumber);
    setPageNumber(itemPageNumber);
  }

  function handlePdfOutlineLoadSuccess(outline:any) {
        setOutline(outline);
    }

  function onPdfOutlineLoadSuccess(outline: outlineObject) {
    console.log("** Outline loaded: " + outline)
    setOutline(outline);
  }

function previousPage() {
    changePage(-1);
  }

  function nextPage() {
    changePage(1);
  }

<Document file="xxxx.pdf" onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}>
...
<Outline className="width:100" onItemClick={onItemClick} onLoadSuccess={handlePdfOutlineLoadSuccess}   />
```

TIA for any insight.